# how to copy a jar file to multiple directorys avaiable in a single directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a jar file that need to copy or replace the existing jar file available in multiple sub directory's under a base directory.

example:
jar names: abc.jar, def.jar

directory structure.

BASE_DIR
       SUB_DIR1(abc.jar, def.jar)
       SUB_DIR2(abc.jar, def.jar)
       SUB_DIRN(abc.jar, def.jar)

Kindly suggest how to achive.

Thanks,
Sampath A

Comment: `cp *.jar SUB_DIR1; cp *.jar SUB_DIR2; cp *.jar SUB_DIR3;`

Comment: @kaylum: You are right!

Comment: Thanks @kaylum for the update I didn't post the entire scenario of the script I posted one scenario where I struct and I need suggestions from stackoverflow and like you people. I have few sub directory's under a base dir I have to copy few jar files to all the sub directory's one by one. I need your suggestion how to loop the sub_dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash v4 like this:

```
for d in SUB*/; do cp *.jar "$d"; done
```

Or with `find` like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name SUB\* -exec cp *.jar {} \;
```

Comment: HI Mark Thanks for the input. I will check and revert.